# MvvmCross 6.0 - TipCalc iOS Sample - Cannot get it working

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am very new to MvvmCross and Xamarin development. I am using MvvmCross 6.x

I followed the TipCalc tutorial and I was able to setup the core project, but, when I tried to setup the iOS project, I did not find any item to add View Controller with xib file in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.

Only options I see is to add a view controller with story board, view controller class and uiview, but no item to add view controller with xib, under user interface.

I tried to add view with a storyboard and decorated the class with MvxFromStoryboard attribute, but the view does not show when I run the app.

What am I missing?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows. I cannot find the option to add a view controller with xib.

Only options I see is to add a view controller with story board, view controller class and uiview, but no item to add view controller with xib, under user interface.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get it working with storyboard. I started from zero again and decorated the class with [MvxFromStoryboard(StoryboardName = "TipView")] and set the Storyboard ID and Restoration ID to "TipView". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio remove viewController with xib template since `15.7`.

If you still want to add viewcontroller like before, here is a workaround.

1.Add `View Controller With Storyboard` first,and remove the `.Storyboard` file.

2.Add `.xib` file and name it as your view controller.

[image]

3.Remove the code which initial viewcontroller in Storyboard way.

[image]

4.Click `.xib` class(blank area) and Link it to your viewcontroller.

[image]

5. Open `.xib` with `XML(Text)Editor` way and add this code snippet under `placeholder` in order to create connection to the view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click -> Add -> New File and select the iOS tab and then select View Controller

[image: Create xib]