# Why "Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Could not load NIB in …" in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, navigation, viewcontroller

I am new in xamarin ios, my app is crashed when running the app and throws an exception "Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Could not load NIB in …".How can I manage it..

Please help me...

Here is my code ViewController

```
 public partial class LoginViewController : UIViewController
{
    public LoginViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public LoginViewController() :base("LoginViewController",null)
    {

    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #region View lifecycle

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
    }

    partial void Btn_Login_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {


    }

    #endregion
}
```

here is my AppDelegate

```
   public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        UIWindow window;
        UINavigationController navigationController;
        UIViewController viewController;

        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        viewController = new LoginViewController();

        navigationController = new UINavigationController();
        navigationController.PushViewController(viewController, false);

        window.RootViewController = navigationController;

        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
```

I got an exception in Main.cs

```
 public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        try
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");

        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Could not load NIB in …

If you initalize viewController using `viewController = new LoginViewController();` , and the class have the constructors 
`public LoginViewController() :base("LoginViewController",null)` , it will look for `.xib` file when running, but Visual Studio removed the template of `viewController with xib` since 15.7, you must create  viewcontroller with storyboard, so the error occurs.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50407112/8187800) to implement the way like before.

---

But we strongly recommend you to create viewcontroller as below.

#### Workaround 1

Create a new class inherit from UIViewController(just a single `.cs`)

```
[Register("LoginViewController")]
public class LoginViewController : UIViewController
{
    public LoginViewController()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view
    }
}
```

But in this way you have to manage UI programmatically.

#### Workaround 2

Create viewController with Storyboard, you can drag `ViewController` from Toolbox to the designer , specify the Class and provide Storyboard ID.

[image]

In AppDelegate modify the way that  initalizing the viewcontroller.

```
//viewController = new LoginViewController();
viewController = UIStoryboard.FromName("LoginViewController",null).InstantiateViewController("LoginViewController");
```

#### A little thing

`Window` is global variable in `AppDelegate` and used in the whole application, you should never create a local variable `UIWindow` ,just use the default `Window`.

Comment: Hi,  did it help or not?